# SQL Spatial Data get data from particular region

Tags: sql, geometry, geospatial

I have a database that contains both text and geography collumns.  The text is a CSV of keywords and the geography is points on a map.

I want to query a particular geographic region for the top X number of recurring keywords and return them in order from most frequent to least frequent. I have no idea if this is even possible or where to start.  Any pointers would be great!

I'm running SQL Server 2012.

Comment: can you change the database schema?

Comment: yes, I have full control over the db

Comment: Do you have any control over the database server? Ditch it and use PostGIS - the free spatial extension to free RDBMS PostgreSQL. Then you have spatial data structures and operations. Its trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. SQL Server (2008 and higher) does have two spatial types, geometry and geography.

Your datamodel could contain two tables, one with geometry and one with the terms/keywords per region.

For example:

```
create table a(id int, geo geometry);
create table b(a_id int, term nvarchar(50));

-- geometry with id 1
insert into a values(1, geometry::STGeomFromText('polygon((0 0,0 4,4 4,4 0,0 0))', 0));

-- keywords for geometry with id 1
insert into b values(1, 'term 1');
insert into b values(1, 'term 2');
insert into b values(1, 'term 2'); -- twice this term, on purpose

-- geometry with id 2
insert into a values(2, geometry::STGeomFromText('polygon((10 0,10 4,14 4,14 0,10 0))', 0));

-- keywords for geometry with id 2
insert into b values(2, 'term 3');
insert into b values(2, 'term 4');
insert into b values(2, 'term 1'); -- shared between 1 and 2
```

And then you create a spatial query, for example looking like this:

```
select a.id,b.term,COUNT(1) as frequency from a 
join b on a.id=b.a_id
where a.geo.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText('polygon((2 2,2 12,12 12,12 2,2  2))', 0)) = 1
group by a.id,b.term
order by frequency desc
```

This will result into:

```
1   'term 2'    2
2   'term 3'    1
2   'term 4'    1
1   'term 1'    1
2   'term 1'    1
```

Which is what was asked for.

Comment: +1 I figure this out last night :)  But this was almost exactly what I ended up with.  Thanks